# Add value for DOM nodes in list

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a list of links using DOM nodes from the data in the database. Instead of having a link for each DOM element. The whole list only have one link. I want the link to be separate because I want to add value to it so I can identify which link the user clicks.
This is the link in HTML

```
    <a href="hearsong.html" id="songlist" value=""></a>
```

This is my Javascript code in which I take data from database. I want to put each corresponding in database as the value for the corresponding link in the HTML code.

```
window.onload = async function outsong() {
        var selected = localStorage.getItem("category")
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = selected;
        var result = [];
        if(selected == "Popular") {
            await db.collection("Song").doc("Popular").collection("songs").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                    result.push(doc.data());
                });
            });
            console.log(result.length);
            for(a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
                var node = document.createElement("li");

                var textnode = document.createTextNode(result[a].song_name);
                node.appendChild(textnode);

                document.getElementById("songlist").appendChild(node);
                var anchor = document.getElementById("songlist");
                var att = document.createAttribute("value");
                att.value = result[a].song_name;
                anchor.setAttributeNode(att);
    }
}
```

In the image, I want to separate the link, not one as the whole.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your loop, you'll need to create a new `<a>` element within each `<li>`, and add the song link to that a element. Modifying your code:

```js
const songList = document.getElementById("songlist");

for(let a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', result[a].song_link);
    link.innerText = result[a].song_name;
    
    node.appendChild(link);
    songList.appendChild(node);
}
```

I don't see where you're getting the song_link from, so for the sake of the example, I guess it was in the `result[a]` object, alongside song_name.

Comment: An `<a>` element doesn't take a `value` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. Your code fix the problem one link as a whole. I am trying to add value to the link but it keeps returning null. Here is the code `link.setAttribute('value', result[a].song_name);`. Sorry, I didn't mention, song_link and song_name are the attributes in my database.